# Achieve Inheritance No Parent Class or Interface

Tags: java, inheritance

I have 2 methods below:

```
void m1(SourceClass s, ClassA a);
void m2(SourceClass s, ClassB b);
```

ClassA & ClassB in fact share some common properties, however, we could not write another parent class & make ClassA & ClassB inherit from the parent class since ClassA & ClassB are out of our control.

Question: without duplicate codes and if ClassA ... else if ClassB ...
What is the best way to handle such scenario in order to achieve the effect as writing a new parent class being inherited? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good design pattern [Decorator Design](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator) that solves:

- Attach additional responsibilities to an object dynamically. Decorators provide a flexible alternative to subclassing for extending functionality
- Client-specified embellishment of a core object by recursively wrapping it.
- Wrapping a gift, putting it in a box, and wrapping the box.

**Note:** Extract the common piece of code in a separate class following [Strategy Design Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) and dynamically change the behavior of an object dynamically.

For example:

```
public class CommonSteps {

   public void perform() {
      System.out.println("common steps");
   }
}

public class A{
   private CommonSteps commonSteps;
   public A(CommonSteps commonSteps) {
      this.commonSteps = commonSteps;
   }
   public void action() {
      System.out.println("some steps of class A");
      commonSteps.perform();
      System.out.println("some more steps of class A");
   }
}

public class B{
   private CommonSteps commonSteps;
   public B(CommonSteps commonSteps) {
      this.commonSteps = commonSteps;
   }
   public void action() {
      System.out.println("some steps of class B");
      commonSteps.perform();
      System.out.println("some more steps of class B");
   }
}
```

---

#### EDIT:

Here is the complete sample code as per your requirement with steps:

**Steps:**

Create an interface `Wrapper` that has common method signatures.

```
interface Wrapper {
    void setP1(String p1); 
    void setP2(String p2);
}
```

Create Class specific implementation of `Wrapper` interface like.

```
class ClassAWrapper implements Wrapper{
    ClassA classA;
    ClassAWrapper(ClassA classA){
        this.classA = classA;
    }
    @Override
    public void setP1(String p1)
    {
        classA.setP1(p1);
    }
    @Override
    public void setP2(String p2)
    {
        classA.setP2(p2);
    }
}
```

Now change the method signature like

```
void m(SourceClass s, Wrapper w) {
    w.setP1(s.getP1()); 
    w.setP2(s.getP2());
}
```

Problem solved

**Complete Code:

```
interface Wrapper {
    void setP1(String p1); 
    void setP2(String p2);
}

class ClassAWrapper implements Wrapper{
    ClassA classA;
    ClassAWrapper(ClassA classA){
        this.classA = classA;
    }
    @Override
    public void setP1(String p1)
    {
        classA.setP1(p1);
    }
    @Override
    public void setP2(String p2)
    {
        classA.setP2(p2);
    }
}

class ClassBWrapper implements Wrapper{
    ClassB classB;
    ClassBWrapper(ClassB classB){
        this.classB = classB;
    }
    @Override
    public void setP1(String p1)
    {
        classB.setP1(p1);
    }
    @Override
    public void setP2(String p2)
    {
        classB.setP2(p2);
    }
}

class ClassA {
    void setP1(String p1) {
        System.out.println("ClassA - " + p1);
    }

    void setP2(String p2) {
        System.out.println("ClassA - " + p2);
    }
}

class ClassB {
    void setP1(String p1) {
        System.out.println("ClassB - " + p1);
    }

    void setP2(String p2) {
        System.out.println("ClassB - " + p2);
    }
}

class SourceClass {
    String getP1() {
        return "p1";
    }

    String getP2() {
        return "p2";
    }
}

void m(SourceClass s, Wrapper w) {
    w.setP1(s.getP1()); 
    w.setP2(s.getP2());
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. to make it more clear, what I have to modify are current codes below: void m1(SourceClass s, ClassA a) { a.setP1(s.getP1(); a.setP2(s.getP2());}     void m2(SourceClass s, ClassA b) { b.setP1(s.getP1()); b.setP2(s.getP2());} --> the point here is: I wish to get rid of duplicate codes without modify signatures of ClassA & ClassB. thanks

Answer (score 0):

why not simply test for `instanceof` ?

e.g.

```
void m (SourceClass s, Object a_or_b) {

    if (a_or_b instanceof ClassA) {
        // do blahA
    }
    if (a_or_b instanceof ClassB) {
        // do blahB
    }
}
```